# Clear login fields after session expires and redirected to login page?

Tags: jsp, session, struts

I'm using struts framework, After session expires I redirect the user to login page. Once the idle time expires, it gets redirected to the login page properly but showing the username and password in the textfields. How to clear the fields when redirected to login page?

```
<%
    int timeout = session.getMaxInactiveInterval();
    String redirect=request.getContextPath()+"/jsp/login.jsp";
    response.setHeader("Refresh", timeout + "; URL ="+redirect);
    response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0,no-cache,no-store");
%>
```

This is the code for session expiration and redirecting to login page

Comment: Post the code of your jsp page on which you are redirecting along with the session.invalidate/set attribute. I will answer you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by putting the value="" in the text fields.

like,

```
<s:textfield name="username" value=""/>
<s:textfield name="password" value=""/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi PKs, I added the code, just see once, I'm using struts1 only. There i'm not even taking the value attribute. But while redirecting it is happening like that.. why so?

Comment: Modify the jsp page and set `value=""` there, does it work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The login fields are probably populated by the browser. Not by the server (checking the generated HTML code would tell you immediately).

And that's a good thing: if the user has chosen to make the browser remember the login and password for your app, then that's what he wants, and you shouldn't forbid it.